# Twilio Line 30: var Twilio = new TwilioRestClient(

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

HI I have been trying to authenticate my new asp.net framework 4.5.2 [WEB FORMS]  website with twilio for a while the website has nothing on it besides the codes I fallowed in the like while updating with my twilio credentials.

Ive fallowed these steps to a 'T' with the latest version of twilio and restsharp. and I have also tried with  using an older package of twilio helper 3.6.23 and restSHarp 104.4.0

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-sms-two-factor-authentication#SMS

But every time I try to add a number it prompts me to locate messages.cs which I don't have in that project

out of severe desperateness one time I eventually have even tried to make a replica one with my identity.config and I copy and pasted everything updated in there to my messages.cs file that I made. but still have the same outcome.

and the only difference that using the older version of twilio and restsharp gave me was to locate core.cs [& I'm not sure what that is] then I click cancel and it gives me this same error in visual studio. like it did all the other versions of twilio and restsharp .

An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Twilio.Api.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.Uri)'.

and then it highlights these lines in my identitiyConfig.cs file

```
            var Twilio = new TwilioRestClient(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["where I wrote my twilio sid"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["where I wrote my twilio auth token"]
);
```

finally after I stop debugging I get this error in the browser I was debugging from

Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.Uri)'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.Uri)'.

Then this line is in RED

```
Line 30:             var Twilio = new TwilioRestClient(
```

Any help will be soooo greatly appreciated or if theres another answer with this exact question that would be amazing as well thanks a ton.

also this in my first year of college in computer science at least so I'm not a programmer genius by any means[obviously lol] but I hope to become one I love to code

Comment: you don't have a reference for a dependency, it could be either twilio or another one

Comment: Thanks for the quick response jack.the.ripper but I added the twilio nuget manager manually through the nugget package manager as well as the consol. and still same error I tried this multiple ways or maybe I'm not understanding what your reponse was

Comment: try to recompile the app see which errors you are getting, do a clean / rebuild for the solution

Comment: That I have done about 12 times and I get the same errors that I have listed in the question :(

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  I'm going to guess 2015, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes 2015..can that be the source of the error?

Comment: You ever get this going?

Comment: Did you ever get this working oExcellent?